# Is there a way to store data into an array from an input file where the name of the array is given in the file?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I want to have an input file with a format like this:
 ArrayName Value
where ArrayName is the name of the array that you want to store the value in.
Each line of  input can be stored in a new or an existing array. The problem I have is that I don't know how to take the ArrayName from the file and create an array out of it. Or if the array already exists I'm not sure how to store the value into the array with that name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would like to name your array from the file, maybe you can explain more about that. But meanwhile one thing you could do instead is:
1. Declare a HashMap of arrays in the form `HashMap<String, int[]>` (that is if your data are integers).
2. Read the name of the array from file and store its elements in the map using array name as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've done it, how will you know which array you've done it to? I suggest you use a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you can read the *key* from your file perhaps with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and clean up afterwards with [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filePath))) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        String[] parts = line.split("\\s+");
        String name = (parts.length > 1) ? parts[0] : "";
        String value = (parts.length > 1) ? parts[1] : "";
        List<String> al = map.get(name);
        if (al == null) {
            al = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(name, al);
        }
        al.add(value);
    }
    System.out.println(map); // <-- print the map.
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```